# Add an existing JPanel to an existing JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

i've got a problem adding a jpanel to a jframe, i don't know why it doesn't appear with other layout that is not flowLayout; i don't use FlowLayout because all my swing components can't positioned.

This is a picture of how FlowLayout shows my components:

[image: Flow layout]

And this is how they should show:

[image: Combination layout]

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: You will need nested JPanels with a combination of Swing layouts to get the components to line up like you wish.

Comment: um,... you kind of need to show us some, code, no? Preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Gilbert Le Blanc, i'm a bit new using Java, so could you explain me what are nested JPanels ?

Comment: Hevercraft Full Of Eels - Well i don't think that any code be necesary to answer my question

Comment: A JPanel can be a component of another JPanel.  That's nesting JPanels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can divide your layout into 3 JPanels, each with their [own layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

[image]

This JPanel can be created (approximately) with a GridBagLayout, 2 columns and 4 rows.

[image]

This JPanel can be created with another GridBagLayout, 4 columns and 3 rows.

[image]

This JPanel can be created with a FlowLayout or a BoxLayout, line axis.

You add the 3 JPanels to a main JPanel with a BoxLayout, page axis.